# Select rows by column value and include previous row by another column value

Tags: python, pandas

Here's an example of DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0, "file_0", 5],
    [0, "file_1", 0],
    [1, "file_2", 0],
    [1, "file_3", 8],
    [2, "file_4", 0],
    [2, "file_5", 5],
    [2, "file_6", 100],
    [2, "file_7", 0],
    [2, "file_8", 50]
], columns=["case", "filename", "num"])
```

I wanna select `num==0` rows and their previous rows with the same `case` value, no matter the `num` value of the previous row.

Finally, we should get

```
case    filename    num
0   file_0  5
0   file_1  0
1   file_2  0
2   file_4  0
2   file_6  100
2   file_7  0
```

I have got that I can select the previous row by

```
df[(df['num']==0).shift(-1).fillna(False)]
```

However, this doesn't consider the `case` value. One solution that came to my mind is group by `case` first and then filter data. I have no idea how to code it ...

Comment: Within one case, if two consecutive `num` are zero, should the first be selected twice?

Comment: @Reinderien No, just once.

Comment: Will `num` always alternate between 0 and 100 in that pattern within a case?

Comment: @Reinderien Sorry for the simple example. Actually, `num` can be zero and any other positive numbers.

Comment: Sure; but specifically - within a case there's no guarantee that every other element is a zero, right? You should update your example to demonstrate this. You also need to show code for the approach you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the answer by myself:

```
# create boolean masks which are true when `num` is 0 and previous `case` is the same
mask = (df.case.eq(df.case.shift())) & (df['num']==0)

# concat previous rows and num==0 rows
df_res = pd.concat([df[mask.shift(-1).fillna(False)], df[df['num']==0]]).sort_values(['case', 'filename'])
```

Comment: so it needed masking/  filtering , shifting , concatenating and sorting :), well done, you had more data to analyse problem better by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
df.join(df.groupby('case').shift(-1)
                .loc[df['num']==0]
                .dropna(how='all').add_suffix('_next'), 
        how='inner')
```

Output:

```
   case filename  num filename_next  num_next
0     0   file_0    0        file_1       0.0
3     2   file_3    0        file_4     100.0
5     2   file_5    0        file_6      50.0
```

Comment: Very close. Concatenate not Nan rows to `num` = 0 rows sounds like the result I posted above.

Comment: I doubt this is what's intended - my read of the problem is that `filename_next` is really just additional rows with no dedicated column

Answer (score 0):

How about merging df ?

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0, "file_0", 0],
    [0, "file_1", 0],
    [1, "file_2", 0],
    [2, "file_3", 0],
    [2, "file_4", 100],
    [2, "file_5", 0],
    [2, "file_6", 50],
    [2, "file_7", 0]
], columns=["case", "filename", "num"])
df = df.merge(df, left_on='filename', right_on='filename', how='inner')
df[(df['case_x'] == df['case_y']) & df['num_x'] == 0]
Out[219]: 
   case_x filename  num_x  case_y  num_y
0       0   file_0      0       0      0
1       0   file_1      0       0      0
2       1   file_2      0       1      0
3       2   file_3      0       2      0
4       2   file_4    100       2    100
5       2   file_5      0       2      0
6       2   file_6     50       2     50
7       2   file_7      0       2      0
```

then you can rename columns back

```
df[['case_x', 'filename',  'num_x']].rename({'case_x':'case','num_x':'num'},axis=1)
Out[223]: 
   case filename  num
0     0   file_0    0
1     0   file_1    0
2     1   file_2    0
3     2   file_3    0
4     2   file_4  100
5     2   file_5    0
6     2   file_6   50
7     2   file_7    0
```

Comment: I think you forgot to shift before merge.

Comment: is shift even needed :) ?

Comment: Yes, _Then, we check their previous rows_. Oh, wait, you merged on `filename`... So no, you doesn't really do anything, just duplicate the data and then drop the extra parts just created.