# How to concatenate csv files and continue the last row value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple csv files which have `case` column which begins from 0.

I want to concatenate them by setting the last `case` value +1 as the beginning value of the next one.

I know I can create a for loop to read each csv file and add the last value to the `case` column in each loop.

```
import pandas as pd

# List of file names
file_list = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']

# Read the first file and store it in a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(file_list[0])

# Get the last value of the column that you want to continue
last_value = df.iloc[-1]['column_name']

# Loop through the remaining files
for file in file_list[1:]:
    # Read the file into a DataFrame
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(file)

    # Continue the last value from the previous file in the current file
    df_temp['column_name'] += last_value+1
    last_value = df_temp.iloc[-1]['column_name']

    # Concatenate the current file with the main DataFrame
    df = pd.concat([df, df_temp])
```

Is it possible to directly use something like `pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, file_list)`?

Comment: Why do you want it in that form? What you have right now already works, and it's very unlikely for a more declarative version to exist already

Comment: I doubt Pandas has any sort of increment-aware functions.

Comment: @Samathingamajig I thought there was a special function in pandas ... Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be efficient to modify each file data, append to a Python list, then concat at the end instead of frequently concatenating:

```
import pandas as pd

# List of file names
file_list = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']

# Read the first file and store it in a DataFrame
data = []
last_value = 0

# Loop through files
for file in file_list:
    # Read the file into a DataFrame
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(file)

    # Continue the last value from the previous file in the current file
    df_temp['column_name'] += last_value
    last_value = df_temp.iloc[-1]['column_name'] + 1

    # different here: append the data
    data.append(df_temp)

df = pd.concat(data)
```

Comment: They already have this style, they want it as a generator for some reason

Comment: I understand, I'm just pointing out that there is a huge different between step-by-step concatenation and final concat.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try as you mentioned is the `map` function

```py
import pandas as pd

file_list = ['dum1.csv', 'dum2.csv', 'dum3.csv']
    
# Concatenate the CSV files into a single data frame
df_concatenated = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, file_list))
```

This however will not update column values. So you have to update them beforehand or after. I'm not too sure about the exact df structure you have but you can try:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize a counter for the case values
case_counter = 0

file_list = ['dum1.csv', 'dum2.csv', 'dum3.csv']

# Concatenate CSV files into a single data frame
df_concat = pd.concat([df.assign(case=df.case + case_counter) for df in map(pd.read_csv, file_list)])
```

Alternatively, you can also concatenate the dataframes with `map` and reset the index

```py
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'index': 'case'}, inplace=True)
df['case'] = range(df.shape[0])
```

This will modify the original DataFrame and reset its index, renaming the new index column to **case**, and filling it with a range of numbers from 0 to the number of rows. You can also do it on a separate column without using the index and not in place by creating a new data frame.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep the `case` values, and just add increments by the previous last `case` value.

Comment: It makes sense if your case doesn't begin from 0, but as long as it does you can just stack CSV files in order (if case number matters) and this way would be faster and cleaner. Not sure why you insist on making it more code-heavy. Looping over dataframes in general is a big no-no for performance.

Comment: I chose to stack csv files in order before. However, in my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74973297/7347925), the second step will ruin the order ...